# Can't connect node js with mysql in docker container

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, econnrefused

[error message I am facing after running docker composee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxoex.png)

```
Express server is runnig at port no : 8000
backend-web-1  | DB connection failed
backend-web-1  |  Error : {
backend-web-1  |   "errno": -111,
backend-web-1  |   "code": "ECONNREFUSED",
backend-web-1  |   "syscall": "connect",
backend-web-1  |   "address": "127.0.0.1",
backend-web-1  |   "port": 3306,
backend-web-1  |   "fatal": true
backend-web-1  | }
```

[folder structure of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjESB.png)

Docker file for mysql

```
FROM mysql
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./mysql.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Docker file of node js

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY *package.json /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 8000
COPY . /app
CMD ["node" ,"index.js"]
```

Docker compose file

```
services: 
  db: 
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    build: ./dbinit
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: timesheet
      restart: always
    ports:
      - "3305:3309"
  web:
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    build: ./app
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: timesheet
    ports:
      - "5000:8000"
```

I've been trying this for three days. Both Node JS and MySQL images can be built, an issue occurs when Node.js tries to connect to the MySQL database.

[here is the code of backend server index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cWaA.png)

```
  // Create Connection

var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'timesheet',
    multipleStatements: true
});


  // Connecting database
  mysqlConnection.connect((err) => {
    if (!err)
        console.log('DB connection succeded.');
    else
        console.log('DB connection failed \n Error : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
});


app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Express server is runnig at port no : 8000'));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for including most things as text. Code and error message could be better as text. Why is the mysql ports "3305:3309"? Doesn't it listen on 3306? Did the mysql container start? What is its logs? Why change the `WORKDIR` in the mysql container?

Comment: Thank you, I included code and an error message as requested. I tried port 3306 as well, but received the same error. Is that why it's not connecting with MySql because of the `WORKDIR` . I am sorry I am new to docker. And the last log comment is ` [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.31'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.`

Answer (score 0):

Although I can see an attempt to set a correct DB host for the `web` service in the docker-compose file, the backend application seems to be trying to connect to `localhost:3306`, which is wrong. From the back-end code snippet you posted, it's hard to understand, how the host should be picked from the `MYSQL_HOST` environment variable.